# Hibernate Java - setting values during running and generate SQL

Tags: java, hibernate

I am completely new to Hibernate, that's reason why I am asking you about it.

Is there any way in Hibernate to create table(s) where during running I am setting values and creating table ? 
It mean that I am able to call methods which sets for example name of table and also name,type of columns and from these input will be able hibernate generate CREATE table SQL with these inputs.
Is it possible in Hibernate ?

I know it is not forum, and that fragment of some code is expected, but I don't know where/who to ask about it.

Comment: Short answer: no. That's not what Hibernate is for.

Comment: And is there any other framwork in java ? What I need is to generate SQL in different sql dialects, I found that hibernate can generate SQL code in different dialects but I stopped my "research" in point where I cannot dynamicly set values into columns and etc. Or is there any work around in hibernat how to do it ?

Comment: Plain JDBC with enough database permissions to do so.

Comment: And what about  QueryDSL SQL ?  Is it possible there to generate sql code in different dialects ? And also set values during running ?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate (/JPA) is not designed to create Database tables while calling custom methods during runtime.

Here is what it does:

- You define Java Beans and annotated them as entities.
- Depending on your configuration Hibernate can perform the following task while starting your application:

  - drop tables and create new ones according your entities
  - create tables according your entities
  - validate the schema if it matches with your Java entities